# How do I find the max value for each 5 minute interval?

Tags: perl

The program below prints the following data:

```
 Wed,Jun,13,10:37:34,2012,759,41,0,30,10,0,0,1
 Wed,Jun,13,10:38:34,2012,767,33,0,25,6,0,0,2
 Wed,Jun,13,10:39:34,2012,758,42,0,32,10,0,0,0
 Wed,Jun,13,10:40:35,2012,758,42,0,29,11,0,0,2
 Wed,Jun,13,10:41:35,2012,761,39,0,34,5,0,0,0
 Wed,Jun,13,10:42:35,2012,769,31,0,22,6,0,0,3
 Wed,Jun,13,10:43:35,2012,754,46,0,29,17,0,0,0
```

I need to output the max value (ex. 769) for each 5 minute interval.  Ideally this would be 10:00:00 - 10:05:00, etc.  Time is military time (24 hour).  What is the best way of doing this?  Please note that I am a beginner in Perl.  Below is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# This program displays the max thread count at 5 minute intervals and writes the lines to a CSV file.

use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

# Initialize functions
my @data;
my $line;
my @L1;
#my $outFivemin = "log_5min.csv";
#open (FiveMin, ">> $outFivemin");

# Open the error_log 
open(FH, "error_log");
@data = <FH>;

# Filter the results to MPMStats only
sub findLines {
    my @return = ();
    foreach $line (@data) {
        if ( ($line =~ /notice/) && ($line =~ /rdy/) ) {  
                $line =~ s/ /,/g;   
                my @L1 = split(/|notice|\[|,mpmstats:,|\t|rdy,|bsy,|rd,|wr,|ka,|log,|dns,|cls,/, $line);
                $line =~ s/|notice|\[|,mpmstats:,|\t|rdy,|bsy,|rd,|wr,|ka,|log,|dns,|cls,//g;                   
                push @return, join("", @L1);
        }
    }
    return @return;
}

# Initializers for my data
my($dayOfWeek1,$month1,$dayOfMonth1,$time,$year1,$rdy,$bsy,$rd,$wr,$ka,$log,$dns);
my($cls);

# Create a 2D array
my @L2 = &findLines;
foreach my $line (@L2){
    ($dayOfWeek1, $month1, $dayOfMonth1, $time, $year1, $rdy, $bsy, $rd, $wr, $ka, $log, $dns, $cls) = split(/,/, $line);
    print "$dayOfWeek1,$month1,$dayOfMonth1,$time,$year1,$rdy,$bsy,$rd,$wr,$ka,$log,$dns,$cls";
}
```

Comment: Could you configure mpmstats to log each 5 minutes rather than 1? it could make you work easier

Comment: That will not work as I need to find that max value every 5 minutes, not just the value at that 5 minute interval.

Comment: `Initializers for my data` -- no, don't do that. The `my` keyword has the special feature to create a *lexical* variable that is only visible in the current block. You should take advantage of that as often as you can: Only create variables within the block they will be used.

Comment: what are "35,2012" and "34, 2012" - are they not data members?

Comment: "Hour:Minute:Second", "Year". Yes they are but the highest value that I need is the 769-type number.

Comment: From your code it looks like your problem is more complex than the one you have stated. None of the records in your sample data comtain the strings `rdy` or `notice` so neither your program nor the solutions you have been offered will produce useful output. It is an acquired skill to be able remove irrelevant parts of a problem, and you should always err on the side of leaving things in unless you are certain they have no impact on any potential solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works(?), (didn't test), and it begins with your loop right after `my @L2 = &findLines`.

```
my %interval;
my %month;
@month{qw/ jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec /} = '01' .. '12';

# Create a 2D array 
my @L2 = &findLines;
foreach my $line (@L2){ 
    #($dayOfWeek1, $month1, $dayOfMonth1, $time, $year1, $rdy, $bsy, $rd, $wr, $ka, $log, $dns, $cls) = split(/,/, $line); 
    #print "$dayOfWeek1,$month1,$dayOfMonth1,$time,$year1,$rdy,$bsy,$rd,$wr,$ka,$log,$dns,$cls"; 
    my ($dow, $mon, $day, $hr, $min, $sec, $yr, $amt) = split /[:,]/, $line, 9;
    my $key = sprintf "%4d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d",
                $yr, $month{lc $mon}, $day, $hr, int($min / 5) * 5;

    if (exists $interval{$key}) {
        if ($interval{$key}{amt} < $amt) {
            $interval{$key}{amt} = $amt;
            $interval{$key}{data} = [split ",", $line];
        }
    }
    else { # first time in this 5 minute interval
        $interval{$key}{amt} = $amt;
        $interval{$key}{data} = [split ",", $line];
    }
} 

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ binary => 1 }) or
     die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV_XS->error_diag ();

$csv->eol ("\r\n");
open my $fh, ">", 'junk.csv' or die $!;

for my $time (sort keys %interval) {
    $csv->print($fh, $interval{$time}{data});
}

close $fh or die $!;
```

I hope this brings you closer to a good solution to your problem.
**Update:** added first field to split and changed from 8 to 9 portions.

Comment: Worked even better than the last! Only it does not output the cls column data (last column).  Also, how do I go about pulling only the last 5 minute interval as well? I need to be able to put XML formatting around it. Thank you so very much for your help!!!

Comment: Wow, don't know why. Maybe its the line ending, `$csv->eol ("\r\n");`. This would be for a Windows computer I believe. If on a unix/linux, maybe that line should be: '$csv->eol ("\n");'.  The line `$interval{$key}{data} = [split ",", $line];` should include the last column, 'cls' when it splits the line. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: Do you by chance know how to pull only the last 5 minute interval (row)?

Comment: Maybe these 2 lines: `my $last_time = (sort keys %interval)[-1];` followed by `print join ",", @{ $interval{$last_time} };`. Give it a try  :-)

Comment: Got the last column issue solved. The issue was that each string in the array needed another comma after the last value. It was splitting early for some reason without it. Your solution above is not working as I get the error: "Not an ARRAY reference". When I try to print the file within Eclipse, I get HASH(0x...) or ARRAY(0x...). Any ideas why I cannot print a value of a hash?

Comment: There is little point in using `Text::CSV` to format your output when you have relied on just `split` to parse the input data. You also shouldn't enable binary mode for text data, and leaving `eol` set to its default is likely to work best on any platform.

Comment: @Borodin You are clearly right. Yes, using Text::CSV is pointless for the reasons you stated. I think I was following the mantra to use the module when dealing with comma separated values, but in this case it was pointless.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you manipulate the date/time in each record to supply a five-minute key, and maintain a maximum for each key.

For example, if a record starts `Wed,Jun,13,10:37:34,2012` then an appropriate key is `Jun 13 10:35 2012`.

Ordinarily this would be a hash, but since it is likely that the output is wanted in chronological order, and extra work and modules are required to provide a sortable date/time string, the program below uses an array of pairs.

The program works by using a regex subtitution `s///` on the time (fourth) field that replaces the minutes and seconds with the first two-digit minute preceding the time: the seconds are ignored and the minutes rounded down to a multiple of five.

A new `[$range, $value]` pair is pushed onto the `@maxima` array if the array is empty or if we are in a different `$range`. Otherwise the `$value` element of the latest pair is updated if we have found a new maximum.

Note that this program expects a log file name on the command line, and will default to `error_log` of none is provided.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

@ARGV = ('error_log') unless @ARGV;

my @maxima;

while (<>) {

  my @fields = /([^,\s]+)/g;
  next unless @fields;
  $fields[3] =~ s|(\d+):\d\d$|5*int($1/5)|e;

  my $range = join ' ', @fields[1..4];
  my $value = $fields[5];

  if (@maxima == 0 or $range ne $maxima[-1][0]) {
    push @maxima, [$range, $value];
  }
  else {
    $maxima[-1][1] = $value if $maxima[-1][1] < $value;
  }
}

for (@maxima) {
  printf "Maximum for five minutes starting %s is %d\n", @$_;
}
```

**output**

```
Maximum for five minutes starting Jun 13 10:35 2012 is 767
Maximum for five minutes starting Jun 13 10:40 2012 is 769
```

---

**Update**

Now that I understand you want the *entire record* containing the maximum value of field 6 for each five-minute period I have written this revised code.

It also works from the contents of your `@L2` array instead of reading from a file.

I am certain this would be far better coded to read from the file in a `while` loop and generate the output directly from there, but unless you show us some log file data I cannot suggest a better alternative than this.

This program continues from the point where you populate `@L2` in your own program.

```perl
my @L2 = findLines();

my @maxima;

for my $record (@L2) {

  my @fields = $record =~ /([^,\s]+)/g;
  next unless @fields;

  my @range = @fields[1..4];
  $range[2] =~ s|(\d+):\d\d$|5*int($1/5)|e;
  my $range = join ' ', @range;
  my $value = $fields[5];

  if (@maxima == 0 or $range ne $maxima[-1][0]) {
    push @maxima, [$range, $value, $record];
  }
  else {
    @{$maxima[-1]}[1,2] = ($value, $record) if $maxima[-1][1] < $value;
  }
}

print $_->[2] for @maxima;
```

**output**

```
 Wed,Jun,13,10:38:34,2012,767,33,0,25,6,0,0,2
 Wed,Jun,13,10:42:35,2012,769,31,0,22,6,0,0,3
```

Comment: @user1488984: I am surprised, given my comment on your sample code. But you are more than welcome.

Comment: is there any way to list the remiaining values for that line as well? ex.Wed,Jun,13,10:38:34,2012,767,33,0,25,6,0,0,2

Comment: @user1488984: now that I understand better what you require I have updated my answer to give an alternative solution. Note that your whole program really requires tidying up but you need to show your source data for us to help with that.

Comment: So close to done!  Is there any way to print the 5 minute interval instead of the exact timestamp?  Also, how do I put this content into an array so that I can export to a CSV file?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Something along these lines should do the trick...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

# Somewhere to store the data
my %data;

# Process the input a line at a time
while (<DATA>) {
  # Split the input line on commas and colons.
  # Assign the bits we need to variables.
  my ($mon,$day,$hr,$min,$sec,$yr,$val) = (split /[,:]/)[1 .. 7];

  # Normalise the minute value to five-minute increments
  # i.e 37 becomes 35, 42 becomes 40
  $min = int($min / 5) * 5;

  # Create push the value onto an array that is stored in %data using
  # a key generated from the timestamp.
  # Note that we use the 5-min normalised value of the minute so that
  # all values from the same five minute period end up in the same array.
  push @{$data{"$yr-$mon-$day $hr:$min"}}, $val;
}

# For each key in the array (i.e. each five minute increment...
foreach (sort keys %data) {
  # ... sort the array numerically and grab the last element
  # (which will be the largest)
  my $max = (sort { $a <=> $b } @{$data{$_}})[-1];
  # Say something useful
  say "$_ - $max";
}

__DATA__
Wed,Jun,13,10:37:34,2012,759,41,0,30,10,0,0,1
Wed,Jun,13,10:38:34,2012,767,33,0,25,6,0,0,2
Wed,Jun,13,10:39:34,2012,758,42,0,32,10,0,0,0
Wed,Jun,13,10:40:35,2012,758,42,0,29,11,0,0,2
Wed,Jun,13,10:41:35,2012,761,39,0,34,5,0,0,0
Wed,Jun,13,10:42:35,2012,769,31,0,22,6,0,0,3
Wed,Jun,13,10:43:35,2012,754,46,0,29,17,0,0,0
```

Comment: This will display the results in a very unnatural order, putting `2012-Dec-25 00:00` before `2012-Jul-04 00:00`.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Fixing that is left as an exercise for the reader :-)

Comment: that's very lame. A proper solution involves discarding your code and starting again.

Answer (score -1):

Whoops, I mistakenly thought that your csv output was the data file being parsed.

Ignore the answer below.

Here is a solution that prints out the original comma separated line. The max value and the time are also available for printing. But I created a comma separated file with the results instead.  :-)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV_XS;

my %interval;
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ binary => 1 }) or
     die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV_XS->error_diag ();

open my $fh, "<", "o33.txt" or die "o33.txt: $!";
while (my $row = $csv->getline ($fh)) {
    my ($time, $amt) = @$row[3,5];
    my ($hr, $min) = split /:/, $time;
    my $key = sprintf "%02d:%02d", $hr, int($min/5) * 5;

    if (exists $interval{$key}) {
        if ($interval{$key}{amt} < $amt) {
            $interval{$key}{amt} = $amt;
            $interval{$key}{data} = $row;
        }
    }
    else { # first time in this 5 minute interval
        $interval{$key}{amt} = $amt;
        $interval{$key}{data} = $row;
    }
}
$csv->eof or $csv->error_diag ();
close $fh or die $!;;


$csv->eol ("\r\n");
open $fh, ">", 'junk.csv' or die $!;

for my $time (sort keys %interval) {
    $csv->print($fh, $interval{$time}{data});
}

close $fh or die $!;
```

The output to 'junk.csv' is:

```
Wed,Jun,13,10:38:34,2012,767,33,0,25,6,0,0,2
Wed,Jun,13,10:42:35,2012,769,31,0,22,6,0,0,3
```

Comment: Thank you! But I'm getting the following errors:

Use of uninitialized value $time in split
Use of uninitialized value $min in division
Use of uninitialized value $hr in sprintf
Use of uninitialized value $amt in numeric lt (<) 
Use of uninitialized value in numeric lt (<)

Comment: @user1488984 Sorry, it ran on your sample file here ok. I'm posting another solution that ties right in with your code that produced the original output. The only thing about it is I have no way of testing it because only you have the data you pulled it out of.